Using который after или
What is the right form of the word который with multiple subjects of different genders?

Мужчина или мальчик, <который|которые>
Мужчина или женщина, <которая|который|которые> ...
Мужчина (или женщина), <который|которая|которые>
Мужчина, женщина или животное, <которое|которые>

Or perhaps such constructions should be avoided altogether because they do not sound right?

Lowkey all of them sound weird since 1-3 cover all possible things/sexes so why not just say whatever the category of person is (passenger, client, user, etc). It would also be more politically correct and inclusive for non-binary people.

As a russian person, I wanna say that in each of the options there will be the word "которые", except the third point.. it is not entirely clear in what context the brackets are here, but I would choose the option "который"

As a Russian person myself, I would definitely say "мужчина или мальчик, который". I am looking for a rule. For example for verbs the rule is singular when the genders match and plural when they don't, even though it sounds a bit weird to my taste.
